# AutoResizeColumn() issue in C#.net

Tags: c#

In C#.net (visual studio 2010)

My Datagrid id is `dg;`

I can't open `dg.AutoResizeColumn()` with dg.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you post your full code and any error messages etc.?  You might get more people willing to help if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

The DataGridView has a method called AutoResizeColumn that take a column index not the column object itself.

So:

```
DataGridView myGrid = new DataGridView();
myGrid.AutoResizeColumn(<index of my column>);
```

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As James pointed out, the AutoResizeColumn needs 1 (or 2/3) parameters. [See this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autoresizecolumn.aspx)

```
public void AutoResizeColumn(
    int columnIndex
)

public void AutoResizeColumn(
    int columnIndex,
    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode autoSizeColumnMode
)

protected void AutoResizeColumn(
    int columnIndex,
    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode autoSizeColumnMode,
    bool fixedHeight
)
```

How are you calling it?

Comment: public void AutoResizeColumn(
    int columnIndex,
    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode autoSizeColumnMode
)